# Solve: Problems with letters, background-attachment and firefox

Tags: html, css, wordpress, google-chrome, firefox

I've a problem with "background-attachment: fixed" in the body class of my css and Firefox.

I've a Wordpress blog and when I load a page in Firefox, everything renders fine, but when the loading process is finished Firefox stops showing the "-" character.

I've tried it in Chrome and there is no problem.

When I disable the "background-attachment: fixed" with Firebug, the "-" character is shown.

How can I fix it?

The most confusing thing is that this error is not on every page.

A page with this error: http://www.kevin-ludwig.de/4-kanaele/

Edit: When I disable the font-family style, the "-" character will show in Firefox, too. But the font-family I'm using supports the "-" character.

Edit2: A Screenshot: [Problem Firefox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/le0M6.png)

Comment: Can you show us screenshot of a section having trouble as in my FF I don't see any problem?

Comment: I've edit the post with a Screenshot and mark all places, where the characters normaly should be. In the sourcecode are the letters. But FF won't display.

Comment: I'm using FF 45.4.0 on Windows 10 and they are appearing fine.

Comment: I use FF 49.0.2 on Win7- I'll test it with an other FF Version. Maybe this could be a bug in the newest version.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I see no problem in FF49.0.2 & Chrome 54.0.2840.71 m (64-bit).

Comment: On a other PC with the same FF Version and 64-bit Win7 is no problem. So i Think it'll be reinstall FF.

Comment: I've solved it. My FF had loading problems.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is caused by disk storage. I had the same problem with FF (latest version 49.0.2) and not loaded me the page totally, while with the other browsers's okay. So, accidentally emptying the PC memory and cleaning up, I noticed that I began to view the complete page.

The solutions are to empty memory or reinstall firefox.